# What does the keyword 'clicks' mean or constitute in web analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I would like to understand what does the keyword 'clicks' mean or constitute in web analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "click" generally refers to a user-driven event. Mostly, this means clicks on links by website visitors (a website visitor actively clicked on a link, leading to a new page).

Comment: So a click that opens another page is considered a click or any action that involves a click on the page?

Comment: yes and no, it's considered a click if the click is measurable. measureable is only something that you expressively count as a click. google analytics for example assumes a pagetrack with a referrer from the same tracked domain as if the user clicked on the link on the prior page (for it's overlay-view). with mixpanel or event-tracking technologies, you'd have to expressively call a javascript-code to send the click-event to the server ...